# ServiceStack Running Migrations in IDE with custom app.config settings

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm following the guidance provided [here](https://docs.servicestack.net/ormlite/db-migrations#run-or-debug-migrations-from-your-ide) to execute migrations within my IDE using an explicit Test Class.

However, the `ResolveDbFactory` fails with an error about the connection string being empty.

`static IDbConnectionFactory ResolveDbFactory() => new ConfigureDb().ConfigureAndResolve<IDbConnectionFactory>();`

The `ConfigureDb` class in my main project is configured like so:

```
public class ConfigureDb : IHostingStartup
{
    public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder) => builder
        .ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
            services.AddSingleton<IDbConnectionFactory>(new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(
                context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                SqlServer2019Dialect.Provider));
        });
}
```

Where `DefaultConnection` comes from a appsettings.secrets.json file configured in the `AppHost` like so:
public class AppHost : AppHostBase, IHostingStartup

```
{
    public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder) => builder
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
        {
            config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.secrets.json",
            optional: true,
            reloadOnChange: true);
        })
        .ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            // Configure ASP.NET Core IOC Dependencies
            services.AddScoped<IEmailFactory, EmailFactory>();
            services.AddScoped<IEmailSender, SendGridEMailSender>();
        });
```

Why is it that the running of the `static IDbConnectionFactory ResolveDbFactory() => new ConfigureDb().ConfigureAndResolve<IDbConnectionFactory>();` line is not resolving the connection string?

Answer (score 0):

In your Tests `appsettings.json` you can specify where your Host project containing your App's Host folder `appsettings.json` is relative to `/bin/Debug/net8.0` that the tests are run from, e.g:

##### MyApp.Tests

```json
{
    "HostDir": "../../../../MyApp"
}
```